# Which scope for bot direct message?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've successfully created a slack bot, with the following scopes: app_mentions:read, chat:write, im:read, incoming-webhook.

The bot reacts to app mentions in channels, but not on direct (private) messages.
Am I missing a scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom will come after: you need to subscribe to the `message.im` bot event in order to be notified of DMs.

Comment: you should mark this answer as the Solution.